# howto send data to (linux based) embedded system

Tags: linux, embedded, connection, arm, send

i got a Linux Kernel from http://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/LinuxKernel running on my ARM board.
I have a connection through serial port to my host system windows,
i also got a SAM-ICE JTAG debugger device.

so how can i send some data from my windows to my embedded linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depends on your at91 controller. Most at91 has two UARTS (some at91 has also Ethernet port). You can use second UART to send your data.

Comment: yes i have 2 uarts on my board, it´s a bit bad because i have only 1 on my host system. But how would it work anyways, i can receive files while i am in the u-boot loader and save it to flash.

Comment: You can configure U-boot to receive files from the Ethernet port (if you have) using TFTP protocol and store files to the flash.
You can also add a functionality that will read file from the UART in textual format (Intel HEX or Motorola S-record) to your u-boot but I'm not understanding why you need to do it from u-boot?
it is easier do it after your application will start.

Comment: Yes i know it works by u-boot and thats what i don´t want to do :) I want to use my Linux OS for receiving the files, but i have no ethernet port.

Comment: if you have two UARTs, you can use one for terminal and second for ppp protocol to transmit data. Please take a look here: http://dp.samba.org/ppp/